# Place 2 divs side by side (align)

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for someone and for the next step i need to align the divs side by side. I already did try flex and it did not work for me.

this is my html:

```
    <!-- starting charts1 -->
    <div id="wrapper" style="width:100%"> 
    <div id="columnchart"></div>
    <div id="columnchart2"></div>
    <div id="columnchart3"></div>
    <div id="piechart"></div>
    <div id="barchart"></div>
   </div>
   <!-- ending charts1 -->
```

Here you can see that I did try the width 100& when I change that to 80% my background will not follow when i scroll weird thing.

Now for the css part:

```
/* BEGIN VOOR CHARTS */
#wrapper {
position: relative;
float: left;
}
#columnchart {
width: 515px;
position: relative;
margin: auto; 
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#columnchart2 {
position: relative;
width: 515px;
margin: auto; 
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#columnchart3 {
position: relative;
width: 515px;
margin: auto; 
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
#piechart {
position: sticky;
width: 515px;
margin: auto; 
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#barchart {
position: sticky;
width: 515px;
margin: auto; 
  left:50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
}
/* END VOOR CHARTS */
```

They are already centered so thats great, that is what i wanted and works. So now I have those divs in center:

```
<div id="columnchart"></div>
<div id="columnchart2"></div>
<div id="columnchart3"></div>
<div id="piechart"></div>
```

Those divs are centered this works great. But now i want to center this one also but next to the above divs:

```
<div id="barchart"></div>
```

I know i'm close but it does not work. I already did read other questions with the same title but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this 'left:50%;'

```
#barchart {
position: sticky;
width: 515px;
margin: auto; 
  left:50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I did now everything is centered. The last one(barchart) needs to be next to columnchart. The last div needs to be side by side with the first div.

Comment: It looks a bit weird right now, but it kinda did work a little.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content in two containers like this:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div id="columnchart"></div>
    <div id="columnchart2"></div>
    <div id="columnchart3"></div>
    <div id="piechart"></div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
    <div id="barchart"></div>
</div>
```

Then add the following css:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;   /* Use this to align center */
}
.cont {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 515px;
}
```

This should center the two sections and placed them one besides the other.